# Why is this crashing on Delete, and why are null values passed into it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm having some difficulty with crashing code in a Delete method (MVC). Here are two methods in my ProductItem controller class. The "Delete" works fine, but I'm getting an error message and when I step through, I notice that the DeleteConfirmed below it is getting a null value for prodID (itemID passes in fine). I have a tough time troubleshooting this because I don't know how the DeleteConfirmed method is being "called" or how the values are getting passed in (or supposed to be passed in) so I don't know what to trace or step through.

EDIT: I removed the nullable from the two arguments for itemID and productID, now it doesn't even get to DeleteConfirmed, I get this:

[image]

```
[ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'prodID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] DeleteConfirmed(Int32, Int32)' in 'Memberships.Areas.Admin.Controllers.ProductItemController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters]
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo) +527
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<BeginExecute>b__0(ParameterInfo parameterInfo) +19
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +58
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +196
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.BeginExecute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +152
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, AsyncActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +179
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32 filterIndex) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32 filterIndex) +629
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +197
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +494
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_1(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +403
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +427
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +105
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163


// GET: Admin/ProductItem/Delete/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? itemID, int? productID)
{
    if (itemID == null || productID == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Product_Item product_Item = await GetProductItem(itemID, productID);
    if (product_Item == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(await product_Item.Convert(db));
}

    // POST: Admin/ProductItem/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int itemID, int prodID)
    {
        Product_Item product_Item = await GetProductItem(itemID, prodID);
        db.Products_Items.Remove(product_Item);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

As requested: The View Model

```
using Memberships.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Memberships.Areas.Admin.Models
{
    public class ProductItemModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Product ID")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Item ID")]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Product")]
        public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Item")]
        public string ItemTitle { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }
}

public static async Task<ProductItemModel> Convert
        (this Product_Item productItem, ApplicationDbContext db, bool addListData=true)
        //Only fill collections if the parameter passed in is true
        {
            var model = new ProductItemModel
            {
                ItemID = productItem.ItemID,
                ProductID = productItem.ProductID,
                Items = addListData ? await db.Items.ToListAsync() : null,
                Products = addListData ? await db.Products.ToListAsync() : null,

                ItemTitle = (await db.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.ID.Equals(productItem.ItemID))).Title,
                ProductTitle = (await db.Products.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID.Equals(productItem.ProductID))).Title
            };
            return model;

        }


private async Task<Product_Item> GetProductItem(int? item, int? prod)
    {
        try
        {
            int itemID = 0, prodID = 0;
            int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out itemID);
            int.TryParse(prod.ToString(), out prodID);
            var productItem = await db.Products_Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync
            (
                pi => pi.ProductID.Equals(prodID) && pi.ItemID.Equals(itemID)
            );
            return productItem;
        }
        catch {return null;}
    }
```

Comment: No "stack trace?"  You need to know who's calling.  Undoubtedly this sort of error is caused by a problem in the calling routine.  (That's why these methods specifically watch-out for Null ...)

Comment: Well, if the ItemID and prodID cannot be NULL, then you should change their signatures to not nullable as parameters, i.e., removing ? marks. If they could be NULL, then you just need to check for that before you call the Remove() because... they can be NULL by your design.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The nullable arguments for ConfirmDelete were an error. I fixed that, but now I'm getting an entirely different error (which I pasted above), and I'll also paste the stack trace. I don't understand what I'm looking at unfortunately:

Comment: @DavidLiang both parameters are supposed to be non-null and I changed the arguments to reflect that. I could check them at .Remove() but they're not supposed to be null anyway. The error has changed to "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'prodID' " so the problem is it's still passing in a null value (the problem is I don't know what "it" is) and I'm trying to figure out why it's doing that and where this method is "called" from.

Comment: @DavidBritz: well probably it would help if you can show us the view model (what `product_Item.Convert(db)` produces) and how you construct the form in the view.

Comment: Okay I'll do that. The funny thing is that the URL on the delete link is correct and BOTH parameters are properly being passed into the Delete ("GET") method. It's specifically the ConfirmDelete ("POST") that gets a null value for one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, oddly enough when I had to copy the code and paste it for a new function. The problem was in the delete button itself. The model used to build the parameter string for the Edit Details and Delete buttons (code pasted below) uses "ProductID" for a parameter name, yet the controller's delete method used the argument ProdID instead of ProductID so it was coming in null!!

```
public string ActionParameters //Build a string containing any id paramaters which are passed in.
{
    get 
    {
        var param = new StringBuilder("?");
        if(ID != null && ID>0)
        {   //If the ID is not null then "id=<ID>" will be appended to the parameter string.
            param.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&","id",ID));
        }
        if ((ItemID ?? 0) > 0)
        {   //If the ID is not null then "id=<ID>" will be appended to the parameter string.
            param.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", "ItemID", ItemID));
        }
        if ((ProductID ?? 0) > 0)
        {   //If the ID is not null then "id=<ID>" will be appended to the parameter string.
            **param.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", "ProductID", ProductID));**
        }
        if ((SubscriptionID ?? 0) > 0)
        {   //If the ID is not null then "id=<ID>" will be appended to the parameter string.
            param.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", "Subscription", SubscriptionID));
        }
        return param.ToString().Substring(0,param.Length-1); //Remove last "&"
    }
```

I found this when I had to copy and paste the code for a similar function and noticed that the arguments didn't match.
Thanks for everyone who contributed!